# How do I learn the grouping function with pivot_longer and names_pattern

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to work on the `names_pattern` agument in `pivot_longer` and I am not sure I understand the grouping function and how it works. I need to pivot the following data frame to match the desired output below.

```
df<-structure(list(Weighted_Ideology =0.514, Weighted_Ideology_se = 0.00, Unweighted_Ideology = 0.51, Unweighted_Ideology_se = 0.004), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyr)
df%>%
pivot_longer(., cols=everything(), names_to=c('Variable',  ".value"), names_pattern="([a-z]+_[a-z]+)_(.*)")
```

Desired Output

```
df2<-data.frame(
  Variable=c('Weighted', "Unweighted"),
  Ideology=c(0.54, 0.51),
  se=c(0.005, 0.004)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `names_pattern` to capture the characters that are not a `_` from the start (`^`) of the column name as a group, followe dby the `_` and then capture the rest of the characters (`(.*)`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c("Variable", ".value"), 
       names_pattern = "^([^_]+)_(.*)")%>%
    rename(se = Ideology_se)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Variable   Ideology    se
  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
1 Weighted      0.514 0    
2 Unweighted    0.51  0.004
```

---

The `[a-z]+` implies only lower case characters, whereas in the column names, there is upper case starting character (`W`eighted_`I`deology). When there are multiple `_` and we want to split at a particular `_`, it may be better to match characters other than the `_` (`[^_]+`) as in the solution above